# Нарушения языковых норм в стихотворении Бориса Пастернака. Случайность или закономерность?

Tags: грамотная-речь, поэзия

Стихотворение Бориса Пастернака «Единственные дни» относится к числу хрестоматийных. Название романа Чингиза Айтматова «И дольше века длится день» представляет собой миницитату из этого стихотворения. Вместе с тем поэтом здесь допущен ряд отступлений от языковой нормы. Наиболее очевидным  из них является нарушение лексико-грамматической сочетаемости в заглавии «Единственные дни». Здесь налицо противоречие между грамматическим значением формы множественного числа  существительного «дни» и лексической семантикой прилагательного «единственные», выступающего в качестве определения.  Другим серьезным нарушением нормы является употребление просторечной формы глагола «стало» вместо «встало». Некодифицированной  с точки зрения строгого ортологического подхода является и форма «скворешни». Случайными ли являются эти отступления от нормы или здесь присутствует какая-то логико-смысловая (речевая, версификационная) закономерность? Привожу для контроля текст стихотворения.

«Единственные дни»

На протяженье многих зим/
Я помню дни солнцеворота,/
И каждый был неповторим/
И повторялся вновь без счета.//
И целая их череда/
Составилась мало-помалу —/
Тех дней единственных, когда/
Нам кажется, что время стало.//
Я помню их наперечет:/
Зима подходит к середине,/
Дороги мокнут, с крыш течет/
И солнце греется на льдине.//
И любящие, как во сне,/
Друг к другу тянутся поспешней,/
И на деревьях в вышине/
Потеют от тепла скворешни.//
И полусонным стрелкам лень/
Ворочаться на циферблате,/
И дольше века длится день,/
И не кончается объятье.

Comment: Мне кажется, что формулировка Вашего вопроса _слишком категорична_. Возможно, следует его "переоформить", допустим, так: _Языковые особенности в стихотворении Б. Пастернака "Единственные дни"_ ?

Answer (score 4):

Это не нарушение языковых норм, это художественная находка очень грамотного поэта (гимназию окончил с золотой медалью, окончил философское отделение историко-филологического факультета университета). Название содержит противоречие, похожее на оксюморон, но дальше, в первой строфе он его объясняет. Прилагательное «единственный» относится только ко дню зимнего солнцестояния, а это действительно уникальный день. Но, согласно естественному ходу жизни природы, день этот повторяется ежегодно. Поэтому - дни.

Поэт описывает дни солнцеворота (так  называют солнцестояние в народе, это что-то от язычества), выстроившиеся чередой в его памяти. Дни многих зим прожитой жизни, и каждый из этих "повторяющихся без счета" дней был "неповторим", единственен в своем роде.

Стихотворение  написано в 1959-ом, в трудное для поэта время. Борис Леонидович находился на семидесятом году жизни, изнутри его изъедала мучительная болезнь – рак легкого. До того -  травля,  связанная с получением Нобелевской премии. Это стихотворение умудренного сединами человека, много повидавшего, как хорошего, так и плохого, осознающего, что смерть близка.   В "Единственных днях" поэт стремился передать самый "облик" дней, посетившие его тогда чувства. С чувствами этими для автора непрерывно связаны впечатления окружающего мира, состояние людей в эти дни.

Зима подходит к середине,

Дороги мокнут, с крыш течет...

.......................................................

И любящие, как во сне,

Друг к другу тянутся поспешней...

Личные переживания поэта соединяется с общими:

Тех дней единственных, когда

Нам кажется, что время стало.

Здесь местоимение нам сменяет состояние я предыдущей строфы, а нанизывание придаточных предложений (Тех дней, когда нам кажется, что...) создает разговорный характер.

Это объясняет и разговорную народную  лексику: скворешня, стало.

Кстати, скворешня - более народное звучание, чем скворечник, и употребляется многими писателями: И В.Астафьевым, и М.Горьким, и В. Бианки. Вот, например:

*Все золотое, все: и люди золотые, и серые сараи золотые, и сад, и крыши, и видная хорошо скворешня, ― что принесет на счастье? [И. С. Шмелев. Лето Господне* (1927-1944)]

*У меня была прикреплена к жерди скворешня, балкончик которой я устроил на петлях, а от него вниз, через внутреннее помещение птичьего жилья, провел шнур.[А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Цусима (1932-1935)]*

А глагол стать в значении "остановиться" и вовсе регулярен в литературе - и у Пушкина тоже конь, например, не *встал*, а *стал*, а встал - если кто-то сидел и поднялся. Время тоже *стало*, а *встало* только у молодых писателей.

Так что всё у него с языковыми нормами в порядке. Другое дело, что не каждый понимает его строки, - это да.

Comment: Браво, Людмила! (Знаю, что подобные комментарии не сооответсвуют правилам, но не могу удержаться)

Comment: В этом стихотворении есть еще один оксюморон: неповторим и повторялся (каждых такой день). Стихотворение, как говорится,  дает пищу и для сердца, и для ума.

Comment: А " солнце греется на льдине","И дольше века длится день",
"тянутся поспешней",

Answer (score 1):

1. *Единственные дни* - да, стилистически это можно подвергнуть сомнению (не в моём вкусе тоже - избегаю такого). Но оправдание поискать можно: понятие "дни" (с грамматическим множественным числом) может обозначать *цельный период* времени (дни детства, дни Блокады...), в котором дни объединены напр. каким-то событием, а не воспринимаются как *череда отдельных дней*. Видимо, поэтическое сознание может уводиться от понятия (единственный) "период времени, когда..." в менее прозаичный синоним "дни", когда автору жалко отказаться от прилагательного "единственный" (а его уже приходится грамматически связать с существительным).
2. "**Стать**" в значении "*остановиться*" есть, в частности, в словаре Ушакова - хотя это и нетипично для современной разговорной речи.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1042046

(см. значение 4, там есть пример про часы и даже кое-что из Пушкина)

3. Скворе**ш**ня - тоже словарное слово, хотя и регионально употребляемое (пометка "обл." - т. е. не хуже "бордюра" вместо "поребрика") вариант женского рода в альтернативу "скворе**ч**нику".

http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ushakov-term-68760.htm

Comment: По второму случаю ("стало") с аргументом можно согласиться: действительно, словарь Ушакова отражает норму, более близкую ко времени создания стихотворения (разница всего полтора десятилетия). "Скворешня" же имеет, как Вы правильно заметили, помету "обл", т.е. относится к диалектным словам. Все слова, включенные в "Сводный словарь русских народных говоров", тоже можно охарактеризовать, используя Вашу терминологию, как "словарные".)