# "Единственные". Когда можно употреблять слово "единственный" во множественном числе?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

Была ранее в одном из вопросов фраза "Единственные из бывших советских республик, вступившие в организацию". Но вопрос был о запятой, поэтому тема о корректности употребления слова "единственный" во множественном числе осталась в стороне. Был также [вопрос о словах "единственные дни" у Пастернака](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/435062/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD.), но он касался частного случая и не внес ясности.

Хотелось бы увидеть ясную формулировку. Мое мнение таково. Можно употреблять мн. ч. только в том случае, когда каждый объект единственен в своей группе, например "единственные дети в семье", но если мы выделяем несколько объектов  из группы, то нельзя сказать о них, что они "единственные в этой группе".
"Единственные из бывших советских республик, вступившие в организацию" — некорректно.

Comment: Мне кажется, что правильно или единствен, или единственен.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, конечно. Исправил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Из [словаря ошибок](https://common_mistakes.academic.ru/385/%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) русского языка:
**единственный** ― поскольку в этом слове заложена некоторая исключительность, уникальность, его не рекомендуется использовать в сочетаниях, вроде *несколько единственных* или *два единственных*, а также *самый единственный*.

Из [толкового словаря](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/54730/%D0%95%D0%94%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%92%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99) (С. И. Ожегов, Н. Ю. Шведова):
**единственный**
*-ая, -ое; -вен, -венна*.
1. Только один.
Единственный сын. Единственная улика. Единственно (нареч.) доступный способ.
**2. мн. Только эти, только данные.**
Мои единственные дети. Единственные свидетели преступления.
3. Исключительный, выдающийся. Единственный в своем роде.

*К XIX веку **единственными регионами**, где люди ещё не были бы знакомы с таким оружием, остались Австралия и Океания* ([Википедия)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BA_(%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

*Потом, это мои **единственные гости**, мои **единственные** старинные **друзья**. Они с их внучкой, вы с Бенечкой — вот и все люди, которых я рада видеть в любой момент* (А. Некрасов. Сильная Женщина, или Обопрись о моё плечо).

*Два государства: Российская Федерация и Республика Беларусь — **единственные страны** на территории бывшего Союза ССР, принявшие ответственное решение о государственном воссоединении* (С. Бабурин. Новая русская империя).

*Они, конечно, **не единственные**, кто умеет превращаться, но в этом превращении особенно разительна разница между похожей на червяка прожорливой гусеницей и яркой, порхающей в небе бабочкой* (ОГЭ 2018. Русский язык. Сборник заданий. 9 класс).

*Единственные* [республики] *из бывших советских республик, вступившие в организацию.*
Мне кажется, что здесь предполагается именно это значение — "только эти, только данные".

Comment: Ссылка на  толковый словарь не работает.

Comment: Все словари говорят, что единственный значит *только один* (да и корень *един* об этом говорит). Словарь Ожегова — единственный, добавивший:  "мн. Только эти". Может быть, это уступка языковой практике?

Comment: Попробую скопировать данные из словаря ещё раз.

Answer (score 1):

Строго говоря, некорректно, но в живом языке почему бы нет? Главный аргумент - так говорят. Об очень немногих из многих вполне можно сказать "единственные". Главное - понятно, что имеется в виду.

Answer (score 0):

Определение *единственные* употребимо лишь в сочетании с существительными не имеющими единственного числа (*шорты*, *ножницы*) или условно имеющими (*весы*, *тапочки*, *очки*).

> Единственные цветы, которые они любят в любой день недели, месяца или
>   года ― это колокольчики.

Answer (score 0):

ЕДИНСТВЕННЫЙ, 1. Только один, всего один. Е. сын. Е-ая просьба. У малыша отняли единственную игрушку. **2. мн. Только те, которые имеются в наличии, существуют.** Е-ые свидетели катастрофы. 3. Исключительный, выделяющийся среди других своей неповторимостью. Е-ое по своей оригинальности сочинение.

По-моему, ситуация здесь обычная. **Из группы предметов/лиц выделяется группа с характерным признаком, и все предметы из этой выделенной группы называются единственными** (значение 2 по словарю), например:

Кеа — обитатели холодного высокогорья, **единственные** из попугаев живущие и размножающиеся на высоте 1, 5 км над уровнем моря и выше. [Андрей Коткин. Самый хищный попугай (2013.04.27) // «Новгородские ведомости», 2013]

Ведь мы ― **единственные** из всех населяющих землю существ, кто живет не только сегодняшней минутой, но в большей даже степени завтрашним днем, порой весьма от нее удаленным. [коллективный. Перед главным вызовом цивилизации. Взгляд из России (2005)]

То же значение **у Пастернака**: из всех дней в году он выделяет дни солнцеворота и называет их единственными.

Comment: Какой словарь Вы цитируете?

Comment: Признание мн.ч. — это уступка языковой практике? Ведь корень ЕДИН говорит об одном объекте.

Comment: Обычный словарь на Грамоте.ру, то есть словарь Кузнецова. И это не уступка языковой практике, а развитие значений слова.

Comment: Достаточно было примеров из словаря. Ваши примеры — нечто другое. "Попугаи Кеа" — это ОДИН вид попугаев, единственный среди видов обладатель какого-то признака. Мы — вид homo sapiens, единственный вид, представители которого живут не только сегодняшней минутой. Такой же пример: единственные тапочки.

Comment: Придется защитить моих попугаев.  Эти примеры из той же темы.  Берете всех живых существ, из них выделяете homo sapiens и всех представителей этого вида называете единственными. С попугаями та же история. Принцип один: выделение группы по признаку. Это может быть официальный вид, выделенный из рода, а может быть, любая группа, которую вы лично захотите выделить, только признак обозначьте.

Comment: Не согласен. Одно дело, когда вы сравниваете разные группы (homo sapiens фактически сравнивается с другими видами), другое —  сравниваете каждого с каждым (А и Б - единственные свидетели катастрофы).

Comment: Фактически,  мы говорим о двух единственных свидетелях катастрофы, а это противоречит рекоммендациям словаря ошибок (см ответ Риммы)

Comment: Берем группу свидетелей (всех происшествий во все времена и во всех местах), из неё выделяем свидетелей именно этой катастрофы. Если это один свидетель, то он будет единственным, но если их двое и больше, то они будут единственными.

Comment: Не то. Группы должны быть обозначены по какому-то **другому** признаку (виды животных) , затем мы объявляем одну группу единственной по **нашему** признаку (думать о завтрашнем дне).

Comment: Вернемся к нашим баранам. Единственные из бывших советских республик, вступившие в организацию.. Группа1 - советские республики, группа 2 - бывшие советские республик (признак 1), единственные, кто вступил (признак 2). Здесь два разных признака, а грамматическая форма одна, другой нет.

Comment: Не то, Вы же не сравниваете  группу 1 с группой 2. Более того, чтобы говорить о единственности, нужно бы хотя бы 3 группы иметь для сравнения.

Comment: Условный пример: Республики на букву А — единственные из бывших советских республик, вступившие в организацию. Тут бывшие советские республики - все рассматривамые объекты. Они разбиты на группы по признаку первой буквы. Первая группа уникальна по признаку вступления в организацию.

Comment: С такими абстрактными категориями, как буквы А и Б,  мне сложно общаться, Вам может  помочь только математик. Кажется, среди нас есть такие.